# linked list get retrieveAt method

Tags: java

I have the following homework assignment:

> Add a new method `retrieveAt` for the class `IntSLList` that takes an integer index position as a parameter.
>
> The method returns the info inside the node at the index position. The index of the first node is 0. If the list is empty or the index is invalid, then display an error message.

I have implemented a solution using the following code:

```java
public int retrieveAt(int pos){
    IntSLLNode tmp;
    int count = 0;
    int c;
    for(tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next){
        count++;
    }
    if(isEmpty()|| count<pos){
        return 0; 
    } else {
        IntSLLNode tmp1 = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++){
            if(tmp1.next == null)
                return 0;
            tmp1 = tmp1.next;
        }
        return tmp1.info;
    }
}
```

It appears to traverse the list properly, but it does not retrieve the correct element.

An example case where this does not appear to give the correct output:

```java
IntSLList myn = new IntSLList();

myn.addToHead(10);
myn.addToHead(20);
myn.addToHead(30);
myn.addToHead(40);
myn.addToTail(60);
myn.printAll();

int x = myn.retrieveAt(4);
if(x == 0)
    System.out.println("NOT VALID ");
else
    System.out.println("elm : " + x);
```

The output is:

```
40 
30 
20 
10 
60 
elm : 10
```

Comment: Kindly make i=0 in your second for loop instead of i=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x=myn.retrieveAt(4);
```

you get the forth element, because you used the magical number 4. I'd suggest using either the number of elements in myn, or find out if you have an easier way to do this in your implementation of the IntSLList class.

Comment: in linked list we count start from 1 ?? i thought it's like the array

Comment: if you start at 0 instead of 1 at 
    `for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++)`
then the list iteration begins at 0, yes.

Comment: So the solution would be to make i=0 like Mr37037 pointed out and also not use the magical 4 in case next time you have more or less elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what addToHead is supposed to do (add at the beginning or at the end).
I created this little example class that does both, please pick the method that fits your terminology.

The example is by no means complete, does no error checking, etc.
I tried to read your code and felt the for loops are very confusing.
Maybe this is what confuses you, too? That's why I made this example, that puts you into the position of each Node to figure out what to do next and works recursively.

The basic operations involved in adding an element are:
Do I know a next node? (is this the end of the chain?)
Should I pass my own value onto the next node or the value that was passed onto me? (where should a new value be added? end or beginning?)

```
public class Node
{
    private Node next;
    private Integer value;

    public Node()
    {
    }

    public void push(Integer value)
    {
        if(next != null)
            next.push(value);
        else
        {
            next = new Node();
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public void unshift (Integer value)
    {
        if(next != null)
        {
            next.unshift(this.value);
        }
        else
        {
            next = new Node();
            next.value = this.value;
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer get(int index)
    {
        if(index > 0)
            return next.get(--index);
        else
            return value;
    }


    public int length()
    {
        if(next == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return next.length() + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node pushedList = new Node();

        pushedList.push(10);
        pushedList.push(20);
        pushedList.push(30);
        pushedList.push(40);

        for(int i = 0; i < pushedList.length(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("pushed element #" + i +": " + pushedList.get(i));
        }

        Node unshiftedList = new Node();

        unshiftedList.unshift(10);
        unshiftedList.unshift(20);
        unshiftedList.unshift(30);
        unshiftedList.unshift(40);

        for(int i = 0; i < unshiftedList.length(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("unshifted element #" + i +": " + unshiftedList.get(i));
        }

        Node mixedList = new Node();

        mixedList.unshift(10);
        mixedList.push(20);
        mixedList.unshift(30);
        mixedList.push(40);

        for(int i = 0; i < mixedList.length(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("mixed element #" + i +": " + mixedList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: here's the output I receive:

```
pushed element #0: 10
pushed element #1: 20
pushed element #2: 30
pushed element #3: 40
unshifted element #0: 40
unshifted element #1: 30
unshifted element #2: 20
unshifted element #3: 10
mixed element #0: 30
mixed element #1: 10
mixed element #2: 20
mixed element #3: 40
```